# How to show success message on page.redirect from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a html form in jsp page which on submit is going to servlet ..After executing the functions in servlet i am again redirecting it to the same jsp page from which it has been invoked with a success message to display now on the same jsp page but i don't know how to do this ...

Here is my jsp form code..

```
 <form action="CallTimer" method="GET">
    <label class="button2">Set Date: </label>
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label class="button2">Set Hour </label>
    <input type="text" name="hour" id="hour">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label class="button2">Set Minute: </label>
    <input type="text" name="minute" id="minute">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" id="Submit">
    <br/><br/>
    <label class="button2">Set File-Path: </label>
    <input type="text" name="filepath" id="filepath">
</form>
```

And here is my servlet redirect code.

```
response.sendRedirect("Automail.jsp");
```

Comment: as per your requirement use of ajax is the best way

Comment: @rocking how to send all the form input parameters through ajax

Comment: give me smetime to write code 4 u

Comment: I gave a small example for jquery ajax please see my answer.Fell free to ask if you have any doubts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirement I would suggest you to go for ajax.I gave a simple example how to pass data to servlet.[Click here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to know more about jquery ajax

```
$.ajax(
               {
                   type: "get",
                   url: "CallTimer", //Your full URL goes here
                   data: { name: name1, date: date1,hour:hour1,filepath:filepath1,minute:minute1},
                   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                       alert("success");                  
                   },
                   error: function(jqXHR){
                       alert(jqXHR.responseStatus);
                   }
               });
```

**note** name-parameter name and name1 parameter value,hour parameter name and hour1 parameter value.Similarily for others.Dont use get action in forms because parameter values will be displayed in the url and also there is a limit of 2048 characters

Answer (score 7):

At Servlet:

```
 // You need to set value in session for redirection.
 session.setAttribute("msg","Success");

 response.sendRedirect("Automail.jsp");
```

At `Automail.jsp`

```
  ${msg}
```

Comment: This is HttpServletRequest session. It will be lost if browser is closed.

Comment: I have earlier used this way but at some one client have blocked accpeting cookies so session.setAttribute() and getattribute() did not work.I have to change to encodeURL() after that

Answer (score 3):

In servlet:

```
response.sendRedirect("Automail.jsp?success=1");
```

In your jsp:

```
<c:if test="${param.success eq 1}">
     <div> success </div>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

**In servlet:**

```
session.setAttribute("message","successful");
response.sendRedirect("Automail.jsp");
```

**In JSP:**

```
<c:if test="${not empty message}">
    <h3 style='color:green'>${message}</h3>
    <c:remove var="message"/>
</c:if>
```

Don't forget to remove variable after printing to not include message after page refresh.

Comment: How is this answer different from @Kerb's answer above?

Comment: @AkinOkegbile The kerb is using URL Rewriting tracking and mine is using Session tracking.URL rewriting adds parameter in the URL of the redirecting page(Automail.jsp) to indicate success message .So Automail.jsp will check whether the parameter success is equal to 1,if the condition is true then it will display the success message.So far this behavior of the Automail.jsp page is good.Now if user refreshes the page the message will still appear even if the data is not entered.In session tracking ones the message displayed it removes the session attribute.So it won't appear again after refresh.